# Laravel how do I get info from several Controllers into ONE view

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am building an app using Laravel. It has the following structure:

**one user -> haOne -> Profile -> hasMany -> Discussions -> HasMany -> Replies HasMany -> Likes**

I have as usual one Controller per Model with the typical CRUD functionality: DiscussionController, PaymentController, ImageController, ProfileController, RoleController, PostsControllers, MessageController.

In the Admin area I manage and view all relevant information about each user.

The route in web.php is:

```
Route::resource('admin-profiles', 'AdminProfileController');
```

My problem is in the **admin.profiles.show** view which is served from this method **AdminProfileController@show**:

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $profile = Profile::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    $page_name = $profile->name;

    return view('admin.profiles.show', compact('profile', 'page_name'));
}
```

Here I need all the information concerning a user (profile, discussions, answers to posts, images, likes, payments, channels, etc).

I could build a GIANT show method in the AdminController and pass a whole bunch of variables to that view, like this:

```
    $discussions = Discussion::where('profile_id', $profile->id)get);
    $replies= Reply::where('profile_id', $profile->id)->paginate(4);
...
    and so on until 27 queries
```

but it looks to me like a bad solution, since I have already one controller per model.

I did call the UserController like this:

```
    <span class="mt-3 small pull-right">
Accumulated Likes: {{ $user->profile->all_likes($user->id) }}
</span>
```

and in the userController I did:

```
public function all_likes($id) {

    $user = User::find($id);
    $profile = Profile::where('user_id', $user->id);
    $discussions = Discussion::where('profile_id', $profile->id)->get();
    $replies = array();
    $all_likes = "";
    foreach ($discussions as $discussion) {
        foreach ($discussion->replies as $reply) {
            $all_likes = $all_likes + count($reply->likes);
        }
    }

    return $all_likes;
}
```

But it did not work.

**How do I call methods in different controllers from a HTML view?**

Comment: {{ WhateverController::public_staticFunction() }}

Comment: @Amarnasan, thanks for the answer, but how do I call that "whateverController" from a HTML view? Because I get the error:
Undefined variable: all_likes (View: ...\views\admin\users\show.blade.php). In the other hand, it means I have to make ALL my methods in all Controllers static?

Comment: {{ \App\Http\Controllers\WhateverController::public_staticFunction() }}. A controller is just another class. If you want to access its methods, you'll need to instatiate it or call static methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything built on relationships, then use them

**one user -> hasOne -> Profile -> hasMany -> Discussions -> HasMany -> Replies -> HasMany -> Likes**

**one user -> hasOne -> Profile**

in UserModel:

```
public function profile()
{
  return $this->hasOne(ProfileModel::class);
}
```

and in Controller:

```
$user->profile;
```

in ProfileModel:

```
public function discussions()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(DiscussionsModel::class, ... youre fields);
}
```

**// similar to the following relationships Replies**

and in Controller :

```
$profile->discussions;

$user->profile; //it's Collections relationships one by one
$user->profile->discussions; //it's Collections relationships hasMany
$user->profile->discussions->first()->replies; //replies to first user discussions. you can go foreach. and so on
```

and in view :

**Controller**

```
public function show(int $id)
{
    $user = UserModel::find($id);

    return view('admin.profiles.show', [
      'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```
<body>
    {{ $user->profile; }} 
    {{ $user->profile->discussions; }}
    {{ $user->profile->discussions->first()->replies; }}
</body>
```

Comment: My question is about HTML. How do I get all those variables from different Controllers into a single View. Since I need everything in one view. I have build all in relations. I have not problem to get all the info in controllers. My Question is how to call that info from HTML

Comment: Perhaps I am not able to explain myself. The question is HOW do I call that function (in your example SHOW). Since I need to call several custom functions in different Controllers (in DiscussionController, in PaymentController, in ImageController, in ProfileController, in RoleController, in PostsControllers,  in MessageController, etc) to feed my Admin dashboard. Eventually I will have more than one function with the same name in different Controllers. If I just do  {{ $variable }} as your example, I get a message error: Undefined variable: all_likes (View:....)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use resources and collections.

E.g. you can create resources for a user with these commands:

**php artisan make:resource UserResource**
**php artisan make:resource UserCollection**

then you include it into your controller, by importing it like so:

**use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;**

In your method, you can return something like this:
**return new UserCollection(User::all());**

The second last step is to make sure you have correctly defined relationships inside your models:

for example, in the User model:

```
public function discussions() {
   return $this->hasMany(Discussion::class);
}
public function profile() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class);
}
```

final step is to call this relationship in your resource, so in your resource, you will be returning like so:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'profile' => $this->profile, // model relationship
    'discussions' => $this->discussions, // model relationship
];
```

with this method, you can do it for all your relationships you need to get for a user.

Lastly, the best practice is to use whenLoaded for a relationship inside your resource:

```
return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'profile' => $this->whenLoaded('profile'),
    'discussions' => $this->whenLoaded('discussions'),
];
```

this way it will load the discussions and profile only if with() is used inside the controller:

```
return new UserCollection(User::with('discussions')->with('profile')->get());
```

this can also prevent unwanted loops, e.g.
User->discussions->User.... etc.

Hope this helps, good luck with your project :)